# how to pass a variable to two different php pages

Tags: php, jquery

i want to pass a submitted value to two different PHP Pages using jQuery and get back the result. I tried below code

```
function showOutput(){

 // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "result.php";
    var bb = document.getElementById("bankbranch").value;
    var bs = document.getElementById("bankstate").value;
    var bd = document.getElementById("bankdist").value;
    var bn = document.getElementById("bankname").value;
    var vars = "bankbranch="+bb+"&bankstate="+bs+"&bankdist="+bd+"&bankname="+bn;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Processing...";
}
```

its sending values to result.php and getting the result in id "status". Now i want to send the same value to another PHP page test.php and get back the result in  id  "test" under the same function name

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's Ajax methods? And what does this have to do with php? You should drop that tag as it's the same wether the backend is php, java or anything else.

Comment: PHP is server-side, Javascript is client-side, how do you think to achieve that? The only way you might achieve that is letting the two PHP scripts share a global variable, set by one of them on some sort of Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

localStorage or cookies to store variable value

and

passing status from url